# RequireJS Setting Path to the Parent Level

Tags: javascript, mobile, requirejs

In order to direct my models, collections, etc. from my mobile app to my web app, I need to configure my RequireJS.

I have the following file structure:

```
/
/js
  /models
/mobile
  /js
  /templates
```

I want my `mobile` app to use my main app's models, so I set the following:

```
require.config( {
    paths : {
        models : '/js/models',
        templates : 'mobile/templates'
    }
});
```

And I get these errors in Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /mobile/js/models/User.js?bust=0.1.0:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /mobile/js/models/InviteRequest.js?bust=0.1.0:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /mobile/js/models/Log.js?bust=0.1.0:1
```

Meaning that it's still looking in `/mobile` instead of `/`.

This path config works for my `templates` folder, but not my `models` folder. How can I point all require dependencies that start with `models/` to my main models folder?

Thanks!

**ATTEMPT 2**

I tried setting the `baseUrl` instead:

```
require.config( {
    baseUrl : '/',
    paths : {
        views : 'mobile/views',
        templates : 'mobile/templates'
    }
});

require( [
    'app'
],
function(App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

I get the error:

```
GET http://local.m.mysite.co/app.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:2
```

Comment: You don't have `<script>` tags in your javascript files, do you?

Comment: No. That error is coming up because the files can't be found (at least that's the reason they are for me). I've tried another solution but still have no luck. I'll update the question.

Comment: Oh, right, the `<` is probably the starting tag in the 404 error page from your server; makes sense.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Does it help to mention that I'm redirecting `local.m.mysite.co` to `localhost/mysite/mobile`?

Comment: @Garrett: it's kind if you accept the answer that someone was nice enough to provide.

Comment: @BrianTopping Thanks! This one slipped under the radar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second attempt, you basically tell Require JS to load 'app' module and since you set the base url to '/', Require JS will look 'app' module in your root path.

So what you need to do is to tell Require JS where to look for your 'app' module. Say your 'app' module is in /js/module:

```
/
/js
  /models
  /module
    /app.js
/mobile
  /js
  /templates
```

Then your code to load 'app' module is:

```
require.config( {
    baseUrl : '/',
    paths : {
        views : 'mobile/views',
        templates : 'mobile/templates'
    }
});

require( [
  'js/module/app'
],
function(app) {
    app.initialize();
});
```

Alternatively, you can set 'module' path in your config. Then refer to this path in your dependency loading:

```
require.config( {
    baseUrl : '/',
    paths : {
        views : 'mobile/views',
        templates : 'mobile/templates',
        module: 'js/module'
    }
});

require( [
  'module/app'
],
function(app) {
    app.initialize();
});
```

As for the error you get in Chrome before your ATTEMPT 2, you will need to look at how you refer to your module in module loading.