# How do I configure a requirejs path to point multiple modules to a folder?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, requirejs

I'm using Telerik kendo controls on my website, which comes with a ton of `.js` files.

I've configured requirejs like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib")',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-2.2.4',
        knockout: 'knockout-3.4.0',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min',
        kendo: 'kendo/js',
        underscore: 'underscore'

    }
});
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
Scripts
  app
    app-related-stuff.js
  lib
    jquery-2.2.4.js
    knockout-3.4.0.js
    bootstrap.min.js
    underscore.js
    kendo
      js
        kendo.all.min.js
        kendo.angular.min.js
        kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js
        kendo.autocomplete.min.js
        ...
        kendo.grid.min.js
        ...
        kendo.web.min.js
        kendo.window.min.js
```

However, if I reference a kendo module like this:

```
require(["kendo.grid.min"], function (kendo) {
    ...
});
```

I get a 404 not found show up in the browser dev tools for this path:

```
http://localhost:2783/Scripts/lib/kendo.grid.min.js
```

It's not picking up my path config and pointing it to `kendo/js` even though it starts with the word `kendo`.

How do I configure requirejs to do this properly so I don't have to manually add a path in for the hundreds of kendo `.js` files?

Comment: /js/* have you tried that?

Comment: @Rikin: Where does that go in the config?

Comment: Here's what I closely found on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816553/requirejs-setting-path-to-the-parent-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a form of pattern matching in the `paths` map but it is a limited one that works only on prefixes made from splitting the module name at the forward slashes and looking whether a prefix exists in the `paths`. If you do `require(["foo/bar/baz"])` RequireJS will check for these in the `paths` map:

1. `"foo/bar/baz"`. If found, will use the corresponding value for the module path.
2. `"foo/bar"`. If found, will combine the corresponding value with `"baz"` to form the module path.
3. `"foo"`. If found, will combine the corresponding value with `"bar/baz"` to form the module path.

**RequireJS does not perform pattern matching any finer than this.** If you have something like `"foo/ba"` in `paths`, it will be completely ignored when it tries to resolve `"foo/bar/baz"`. There is no support for the globs that are supported by shells and similar tools, or regular expressions.

Options:

1. Put all Kendo files under `lib`. They all start with `kendo.` and are thus easily identifiable anyway.
2. Create a minimal mapping for Kendo files. The `paths` would contain `k: "kendo/js"` and you would refer to the Kendo files as `"k/kendo.grid.min"` and so on.
3. Write a script to generate your RequireJS configuration. It would scan the directory that contains the Kendo files and create a `paths` that include one entry per file.